# Yodlee with Symfony2 integration

Tags: symfony, yodlee

Please, I can not find a way to connect with Yodlee from Symfony2. Anyone have any demo you can give me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to create a bundle for everything related to your interaction with Yodlee.
Then, to communicate with the API in PHP you can use a library called Guzzle ( GuzzleHttp ), very handy and easy to implement.

It's pretty basic, the only tricky part is with the Fastlink integration that will require you some work and logic with the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You can find official samples for PHP on the Yodlee Developer homepage.

> You'll need to be logged in as a registered user to download YI WSDLs,
>   Javadocs, and samples in C#, Java, Php and Ruby.

http://developer.yodlee.com/Sample_Applications